# How to get dynamic ref on React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an element with this ref

```
ref={`inner-player${this.props.position}`}
```

and in a function I need to work with that ref doing something like this

`const chipBetImage = this.refs.inner-player${this.props.position};`

but I am getting an error

```
./app/components/ui/PlayerSlot/index.js
Module build failed: SyntaxError: /home/marcelo/Documents/Projects/application-playerinterface/app/components/ui/PlayerSlot/index.js: Unexpected token (150:50)
  148 |       this.props.addMoney({position : this.props.position, currentBet : this.props.currentBet});
  149 |     } else {
> 150 |       const chipBetImage = this.refs.inner-player${this.props.position};
      |                                                   ^
  151 |       chipBetImage.classList.add('animated', 'pulse');
```

so, which is the way to do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`${}` is only valid inside template literals. `this.refs.inner-player${this.props.position};` is not a template literal.

If you want to use a computed property name, you have to use bracket notation:

```
this.refs[`inner-player${this.props.position}`]
```

See [Dynamically access object property using variable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4244896/218196) .